# What are html page size limitations

Tags: html, html-table

My application can export a table of arbitrary size to HTML file, it consists of a single `<table>` with some CSS styles added.

I want to give a warning or forbid export when the table is too big.

While there are upper bounds on size of Excel sheets i fail to find such restrictions for

- number of rows and columns in HTML table
- total size of HTML file intended to be opened in a browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any, at least none imposed by the specification.

At some point, you'll hit limits of memory and/or CPU, but that will depend mostly on the computer that is rendering the webpage.